# :sbr opens buffers with horizontal split, even with switchbuf set to vsplit

Tags: split

I've set `switchbuf` to `vsplit` but when I use `:sbr`, vim uses a horizontal split to open the new buffer. This seems directly contrary to what `:help sbr` says:

```
:sbr[ewind] [+cmd]
    Split window and go to first buffer in buffer list.  If the
    buffer list is empty, go to the first unlisted buffer.
    Respects the 'switchbuf' option.
```

And `:help switchbuf` says:

```
   split    If included, split the current window before loading
        a buffer for a |quickfix| command that display errors.
        Otherwise: do not split, use current window.
   vsplit   Just like "split" but split vertically.
```

The output of `:version` (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04's `vim-gtk3-py2`):

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
```

I know about `:vert sbr`, and I can make an alias to make that more convenient, but I'd really like to figure out what's causing `switchbuf` to not work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: What's the specific command you're using to set `switchbuf` and, perhaps more importantly, what's the output of `:set switchbuf?` immediately before using `:sbr`?

Comment: Although, given that my own testing shows that `:set switchbuf=vsplit` followed by `:set switchbuf?` prints `vsplit`, and following that with `:sbr` results in a horizontal split, I'm inclined to think you may have found a bug. Seems to ignore `switchbuf=newtab` as well. And `:sbnext` misbehaves in the same manner as `:sbr`.

Comment: I've tried both with `set switchbuf=vsplit` in .vimrc and with `:set switchbuf` and `:setlocal switchbuf` (didn't expect that one to work, but worth a shot); `set switchbuf?` gives `switchbuf=vsplit` right before `:sbr`, just as you said.

Comment: Alright then, to the mailing list I guess! I'll report back.

Comment: Phew, got through the moderation queue, the thread is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/ORzFkptXfek